# Would a unordered_map be a good choice?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, std

I'm wondering if an unordered_map would be a good choice as container for my specific problem. What I've read about maps does not really cover my are, which is:

- The container will store between 100 and 500 objects (not
  int/double...)
- The size will never change.
- The order is not important as the objects themselves contain some kind of "index".
- Very often (!) I need to filter all elements in the container that have some
  property (e.g. have `color==blue`)

Currently I use vectors, which works. However if e.g. an unordered_map would improve performance (in regard to "filtering") I could image to change that.

Comment: Best way to find out is to try it :)

Comment: If all of the information about the objects that need to be filtered are in the object then I would use a `std::array` if you are okay with wasting space or a `std::vector`

Comment: are there multiple different properties per element which the container can be filtered for?

Comment: More information is needed about the kind of filtering you plan to do. If this is filtering on a single attribute, and you don't need to iterate over entire unfiltered set, then an unsorted_map of vectors or arrays could be useful. I forget - is there sucha thing as unsorted_multimap?

Comment: @Arkadiy Yes, there is.

Comment: Try it and measure it..........????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` wouldn't really help you if you have multiple search criteria (sometimes `color == blue`, sometimes `flavour == up`), because maps only offer fast query on a single, pre-determined key.

I'd say `std::vector` is just fine for you, ideally wrapped in your own structure which will provide the lookup interface. If profiling later tells you this is not fast enough, you could build your own indexes above such data. You wouldn't even have to do that manually, [`boost::multi_index`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) is a generic container designed for multiple-criterion lookup.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `vector` or simply array for storing actual data. And have a few `map`s that maps key with pointer to actual data.

This would give higher memory usage, but in case searching by different indexes is often needed you may sacrifice a bit of memory.

Answer (score 1):

A hash table (which `std::unordered_map` is) provides constant-time lookup for one key (key-value pair). However, its constant factors are **always** higher (i. e. the lookup is slower) than a simple array (which provides constant-time lookup for integer indices).

If you need to filter a collection of elements based on some criteria, then you need to inspect each individual element. In this case, a hash table would be **strictly worse** than an array/vector performance-wise, since its computational complexity is the same as that of array indexing, but with worse constant factors.

So no, there's no reason why you would want to use an `unordered_map` in this case.